# Question about baggage transfer at EWR from Terminal C to Terminal B

Tags: luggage, layovers, airport-transfer, united-airlines, air-india

I have booked my flight from Detroit to India & I have my 3 hr layover at EWR airport. I will have to change the terminal when I land at EWR airport from terminal C to terminal B. Will my checked-in baggage be transferred b/w terminals, or will I have to go take my baggage and check in again at terminal 2 of EWR airport?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is your travel on the same ticket or you booked two separate tickets between Detroit and EWR and between EWR and India?

Answer (score 1):

Standard answer:

If you booked this on a single ticket (for example United to Lufthansa), the luggage will get checked through to the final destination. You MAY be able to take an airside shuttle from C to B and not have to go through security again. See https://www.newarkairport.com/at-airport/connecting-flights. 3 hours should be plenty

If you booked this as two different tickets, you need to exit the secure area, collect your bags, bring them to the check in counter of the departing airline, and go through security again. 3 hours may or may not be enough for this and you carry the full risk of a missed connection.

Comment: In the separate tickets scenario, do not forget that you need to check-in/drop bags for the second flight **before the check-in deadline** for that flight, which in the case of both United and Air India is one hour before the flight.

Comment: Hi, I have booked both of my flights on same ticket (United and then AirIndia, both are member of star alliance), although have different PNR for each airline. I am able to see both of my flights when I go to United Booking either AirIndia Booking. Does this mean my luggage will reach at final destination irrespective of terminal change? @jcaron

Comment: @KushTrivedi Yes, your luggage should be "checked-through" and in this scenario you won't see it, it will transferred from one flight to the other (you're in the first scenario given above). The other way around (India -> EWR -> DTW) would be different.